# Numpy function output increases with every run

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Minimum working example:

```py
import numpy as np

datatest = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 2], [3, 3, 3]])

def sumcols(data):
    temp = np.empty(data.shape[0])
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        for j in range(data.shape[1]):
            temp[i] += data[i,j]
    return temp

sumcols(datatest)
```

The `datatest` is the following array:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 1, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])
```

I'm simply trying to sum the values in the columns (and or the rows).

The weird part. When I run this function (ie. `sumcols(datatest)`) multiple times, each result is larger than the next. This value behavior persists *with different function names*:

```
n [4]: def means(data): 
   ...:     temp = np.empty(data.shape[0]) 
   ...:     for i in range(data.shape[0]): 
   ...:         for j in range(data.shape[1]): 
   ...:             temp[i] += data[i,j] 
   ...:     return temp 
   ...:                                                                                                            

In [5]: means(datatest)                                                                                            
Out[5]: array([6., 4., 9.])

In [6]: means(datatest)                                                                                            
Out[6]: array([12.,  8., 18.])

In [7]: means(datatest)                                                                                            
Out[7]: array([18., 12., 27.])

In [8]: means(datatest)                                                                                            
Out[8]: array([24., 16., 36.])

In [9]: means(datatest)                                                                                            
Out[9]: array([30., 20., 45.])

In [10]: def sumcols(data): 
    ...:     temp = np.empty(data.shape[0]) 
    ...:     for i in range(data.shape[0]): 
    ...:         for j in range(data.shape[1]): 
    ...:             temp[i] += data[i,j] 
    ...:     return temp 
    ...:                                                                                                           

In [11]: sumcols(datatest)                                                                                         
Out[11]: array([36., 24., 54.])

In [12]: sumcols(datatest)                                                                                         
Out[12]: array([42., 28., 63.])

In [13]: sumcols(datatest)                                                                                         
Out[13]: array([48., 32., 72.])

In [14]: sumcols(datatest)                                                                                         
Out[14]: array([54., 36., 81.])

In [15]: sumcols(datatest)                                                                                         
Out[15]: array([60., 40., 90.])

In [16]: sumcols(datatest)                                                                                         
Out[16]: array([66., 44., 99.])

In [17]: sumcols(datatest)                                                                                         
Out[17]: array([ 72.,  48., 108.])
```

How is this happening? I'm not assigning a variable inside or outside the function *and* the `temp` variable is reset every function call.

Edit:

The issue appears to be related to the `temp` variable being declared empty. If I change `temp = np.empty(data.shape[0])` to `temp = np.zeros(data.shape[0])`, it works correctly. I'm working on submitting an issue to the numpy devs to check if this is desired behavior.

Edit 2:
Someone already wrote [an issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12003). As expected, this is desired behavior and won't be changed.

### tl;dr

Initialize with `np.empty` only if you explicitly submit results.
Otherwise, use a different initialization for your specific case (`np.zeros`) for me.

Comment: You explicitly ask for an unitialized array, and then you just increment its values. you just call the same function repeatedly, it happens to always allocate its buffer at the same address. And since it's uninitialized, the values can be anything... like the values from the previous call of the function. In fact, you could have easily gotten complete garbage on the first iteration.

Comment: `temp = np.empty(data.shape[0])` ->> `temp = np.zeros(data.shape[0])`

Comment: ... `datatest.sum(-1)` - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html

Comment: @wwii I'm aware. This was a minimal working example of a more complicated problem.

Answer (score 1):

Want to see something even more fun? If you change the definition of `sumcols` to:

```
def sumcols(data):
    temp = np.empty(data.shape[0])
    temp2 = np.empty(data.shape[0])
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        for j in range(data.shape[1]):
            temp2[i] += data[i,j]
    return temp2
```

after you've already run the original definition a few times, you'll notice that this function will continue incrementing the same values where the old version left off.

It seems that `numpy` has a specific region in memory that it always likes to start at when allocating memory for new variables. If you keep calling `np.empty` for an array of the same size, you'll keep getting the same block of memory and therefore the same values, since you're not initializing it first.

Answer (score 0):

it also looks like you could solve this problem in a simpler way, by just accessing every column in every row, then you won't have to deal with library problems:

```
def sumCols(list):
    sums = []
    for i in list:
        sum = 0
        for j in i:
            sum += j
        sums.append(sum)
    return(sums)
```

Comment: Or just - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html